# JQGrid Column Width Always auto width

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

Recently upgraded from jqGrid 4.4.4 Retro version to jqGrid 4.13.5.It was working fine with old one. Now the columns width are conjested.

```
$("#gridViewEditable").jqGrid({
        datatype: "local",
        data: data,
        cmTemplate: { autoResizable: true ,resizable : false,shrinkToFit:false,autowidth:false},
        autoResizing: { compact: true },
        gridview:true,
        loadonce:true,
        autowidth:false,
        shrinkToFit:false,
        pager: '#gridViewEditablePager',
        rownumbers: true,
        pgbuttons :false,
        viewrecords : false,
        pgtext : "",
        pginput : false,
        ignoreCase: true,
        viewrecords: true,
        caption: "Services",
        editurl: 'clientArray',
        footerrow: true, .........
```

Old JqGrid
[image: Old JqGrid]

New JQgrid
[image: New JQGrid]

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: I suppose that you don't included `ui.jqgrid.min.css`. See [here](https://free-jqgrid.github.io/getting-started/index.html) and [here](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs) for details.

Comment: @Oleg no i tried with you cdn link also it is not working https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/free-jqgrid/4.13.5/css/ui.jqgrid.min.css

Comment: @thalla: You should prepare **the demo**, which reproduce the problem.

Comment: s but i think it too complex to reproduce the problem let me try

Comment: @Oleg got answer while creating demo. in my css i used " table {  
        table-layout: auto !important;
    }" thanks

Comment: @Oleg please consider to include my edit also it may help others.

Comment: @Oleg is it possible to keep all jqgrid row in edit style always(without double click). suggestion from one of client

Comment: You can click on "edit" link of your question to add any additional information. For example you can append the text with words like "SOLUTION:" following details.

Comment: I don't recommend you to hold rows in editing mode. It has many disadvantages. Just someone: 1) the user edit some data in one row, then it edit in some other rows. He think that the changes are saved and can go to another URL, but the data are not saved till the user press ENTER key or click Save button (depend on the options of inline editing, which you use). 2) The user can go to the next/previous page and the data will stay unsaved. 3) sorting of grid, which rows are in editing mode, is blocked. One can block paging too. In any way the user can have misunderstanding about *saving* the data

Comment: @Oleg thanks for your help, after deleting a row my entire page is disabled.can you help me ?

Comment: I repeat once more: **please provide the demo which demonstrate the problem**. You can easy create the demo in JSFiddle for example. It's impossible to help you if I have to guess what you do.

Comment: @Oleg ok, can u please tell me how to change delete dialoge cancel button icon ? not found any documentation on that.

Comment: @Oleg question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40589979/jqgrid-make-delete-dialog-non-resizable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose that you don't included `ui.jqgrid.min.css` (or included it with the wrong path). See [here](https://free-jqgrid.github.io/getting-started/index.html) and [here](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs) for details.