# jqGrid : make delete dialog non resizable

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

How to make jqgrid delete dialog non resizable? And also I want to change cancel button icon.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use delete option `resize` and `cancelicon`. Be carefully that `cancelicon` (in the same way like `delicon` option) has array format with 3 elements (see [the old documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#properties2)). In case of usage free jqGrid you can specify delete option inside of `formDeleting` option of *jqGrid*. For example

```
formDeleting: {
    delicon: [true, "left", "ui-icon-trash"],
    cancelicon: [true, "left", "ui-icon-closethick"],
    resize: false
}
```

changes the default Delete dialog (in case of usage jQuery UI icons) from default

[image]

to

[image]

You should of cause use the icon classes from the `iconSet`, which you use in the grid. For example, if you included [Font Awesome](http://fontawesome.io/) CSS and the option `iconSet: "fontAwesome"`, then default Delete dialog looks like

[image]

by usage

```
formDeleting: {
    delicon: [true, "left", "fa-scissors"],
    cancelicon: [true, "left", "fa-times"],
    resize: false
}
```

you can change it to the following

[image]